# how to find calling method when we know the called method in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

i wrote one app it consist of tens of classes, after some time while i am looking  into my code i faced a problem, i am looking calling function but i am unable to find called function where exactly called method is???.....is there any method to find called method when we know the calling method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode edit menu there is an item called `Find`.  It has a submenu of which the first item is `Find in project`.  Select this, type the name of the method you are looking for and press return.  It will list all lines of code with that text on them.  Double click one to open the corresponding file.